# CSS Padding Navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation, padding, overlapping

Alrighty so I am attempting to create a header for a website I'm making, but I'm having a bit of trouble with padding some links out for my top level nav.

Basically what's happening is, if I have a long link name, it overlaps with another link. 
I think this is something to do with the width but I'm not sure how I can fix it. I also really don't want to create a fixed width for the links, as I am wanting to make each text in the links 60px away from the previous.

HTML:

```
<nav id="top_navigation">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Example1</a>
    <a href="#">Longtextjustbecause</a>
    <a href="#">Testpage3thingy</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#top_navigation a {
display: inline-block;
height: 60px;
color: #3b3b3b;
font-family: Hero;
font-size: 26px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 60px;
padding: 0px 30px; }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to provide relevant code, this works just fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/PzZ59/

Comment: That's literally the only code there aside the HTML tags. But I think it might actually be the font that I'm using itself..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so it turned out to be the font that I was using for some reason. It doesn't appear to like padding in any circumstance very much.